# Conics and Loci Question (Hyperbolae and Circles)

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections, hyperbolic-geometry

A circle has the equation $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. Tangents are drawn from a point $P(x_1,y_1)$ to the circle and these touch the circle at points $A$ and $B$. If the position of $P$ can vary and the locus of $P$ is a hyperbola, of eccentricity $e$, whose centre is the origin, show that the chord $AB$ touches another hyperbola, eccentricity $E$, where $\frac{1}{E^2}+\frac{1}{e^2}=1$.

I've found the equation of the chord to be $xx_1 + yy_1 = r^2$, but cannot progress much further. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is $e$ independent of $r?$ If not, how related?

Comment: Can you give any further help? I'm still very unsure as to how to progress. Usually it's all about eliminating parameters but it just ends up in a mess of algebra.

Comment: A possible approach.  Parametrize the $E$ hyperbola with one parameter. Find inversion with respect to this circle radius $r$ and eliminate the parameter by C discriminant method. Something extra is also involved further...

Comment: Would it be possible to use an envelope method to get the hyperbola from the chord equation (involving partial derivatives)?

Comment: As an aside, the midpoint of *AB* describes a [lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate).

Comment: The midpoint of AB has coordinates given by $x = \frac{x_1r^2}{x_1^2 + y_1^2}$ and  $y = \frac{y_1r^2}{x_1^2 + y_1^2}$, is this correct? Seems very tricky to eliminate the parameters...

Comment: @wrb98: Your midpoint coordinates are correct. You could eliminate the parameters using the method of "resultants" ... however, there's nothing to suggest that chord $AB$ touches the new hyperbola at its midpoint.

Comment: To your earlier comment about envelopes: Yes, you can use the partial derivative approach. Writing your chord equation as $F(u) = x x_1 + y y_1 - r^2$ with the substitutions $$x_1 = h + a \cosh u \qquad\qquad y_1 = k + b \sinh u$$ (where $(h,k)$ is the center of the hyperbola, and $a$ and $b$ are the semi-transverse and -conjugate axes). Then $F^\prime(u)$ is easily computed. Eliminating the $u$ terms isn't terribly difficult (there's a nice trick). You'll get a conic equation with an $xy$ term, so there'll be some work left to determine its eccentricity.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The hyperbolae are related to their inversions with respect to circle $r$.